# VHDL error in For loop

Tags: vhdl

In the following code I receive the following errors, but  I don't understand why is it an error.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity RGSTR_SHFT_N_PARAL_B2 is

Generic (
     n: integer := 4  
     );

  port(
    DATA : in std_logic_vector((n-1) downto 0); 
    Shift_In : in std_logic; 
    Load : in std_logic;  
    Enable : in std_logic;  
CLK : in    std_logic;  
S : out   std_logic_vector((n-1) downto 0)   
        );
end entity RGSTR_SHFT_N_PARAL_B2;

architecture simple of RGSTR_SHFT_N_PARAL_B2 is

  signal temp_S: std_logic_vector((n-1) downto 0);

  signal LOW0, HIGH1: std_logic; -- Constant Signals   

  -- Use the D flip flop of B1 excersise
      component D_FF_B1 is
        port( 
        Enable      : in    std_logic;  
       Load        : in std_logic;  
    Load_Val    : in    std_logic;  
     Data_in     : in   std_logic;  
     CLK        : in    std_logic;  
     Q           : out   std_logic  
    );
  end component;

begin

  p0:process(Enable, CLK) is
  begin

-- Initialisations 

  LOW0  <= '0';
  HIGH1 <= '1';

    if (Enable = LOW0) then
           L0: for i in 0 to (n-1) loop
              temp_S(i) <= temp_S(i);
           end loop;
       elsif (CLK 'event and CLK = HIGH1) then 
           if (Load = LOW0)  then             -- Shifter is enabled
              L1: for i in 0 to (n-2) loop
                  temp_S(i) <= temp_S(i+1);
              end loop;
              temp_S(n-1) <= Shift_In;
           else                               -- Loader is enabled
              L2: for i in 0 to (n-1) loop
                X1: D_FF_B1 port map(HIGH1, LOW0, LOW0, DATA(i), CLK, temp_S(i));
              end loop;
           end if;
       end if;

  L3: for i in 0 to (n-1) loop
     S(i) <= temp_S(i);
  end loop;

  end process p0;

end architecture simple;
```

Error message:

```
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at RGSTR_SHFT_N_PARAL_B2.vhd(79) near text "port";  expecting "(", or "'", or "."
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at RGSTR_SHFT_N_PARAL_B2.vhd(79) near text ";";  expecting ":=", or "<="
```

I compile the VHDL program with Quartus II.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiation of a module in a `process` is not legal VHDL syntax, as seen in:

```
p0:process(Enable, CLK) is
begin
...
  L2: for i in 0 to (n-1) loop
    X1: D_FF_B1 port map(HIGH1, LOW0, LOW0, DATA(i), CLK, temp_S(i));
  end loop;
...
end process p0;
```

Instantiation of a module must be done as concurrent statement outside the `process`.

Based on the code, it looks like it may be possible to move the module instantiation
outside the `process` with code that looks something like:

```
signal temp_S_x1 : std_logic_vector((n-1) downto 0);
...
L2 : for i in 0 to (n-1) generate
  X1 : D_FF_B1 port map(HIGH1, LOW0, LOW0, DATA(i), CLK, temp_S_x1(i));
end generate;
...
p0 : process(Enable, CLK) is
  ...
  L2: for i in 0 to (n-1) loop
    temp_S(n-1) <= temp_S_x1(i);
  end loop;
```

Note that you should declare the constants `LOW0` and `HIGH1` with `constant`
instead of `signal`, and then remove the `LOW0` and `HIGH1` assign in `p0` `process`:

```
constant LOW0 : std_logic := '0';
constant HIGH1 : std_logic := '1';
```

or simply use '0' and '1' directly instead of declaring any constants.

Also note that the `p0` `process` is not a properly formated process for flip
flops, so you will get some additional warnings from Quartus due to missing
`temp_S` signal in sensitivity list.  If `Enable` is use synchronously, then
use a template like:

```
p0 : process(Enable, CLK) is
begin
  if rising_edge(CLK) then
    if (Enable = '0') then
```

Comment: So I should not use a process for my program... or is there another way?

Comment: @G.V.: See added example in answer above.